# Does EclipseLink have some similar functionality like Hibernate Interceptors?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

Found a way to use an enum as the entity with its own table in JPA using Hibernate Interceptors.
For example, I want to use as an entity following enum:

```java
@Entity
public enum Color {

    RED(255, 0, 0),
    GREEN(0, 255, 0),
    BLUE(0, 0, 255)

    @Id
    public final byte id = (byte)ordinal();

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    public final String name = name();

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public final int red;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public final int green;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public final int blue;

}
```

To make JPA correctly work with that entity, we can write the following Interceptor, that converts an enum to it's ordinal to save in database:

```java
public class EnumAsEntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object instantiate(String entityName, EntityMode entityMode, Serializable id) {
        try {
            Object o;
            Class cls = Class.forName(entityName);
            if (cls.isEnum() && id instanceof Number) {
                o = cls.getEnumConstants()[((Number)id).intValue()];
            } else {
                o = super.getEntity(entityName, id);
            }
            return o;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

After enabling this interceptor, we can work with the enum entity:

```java
entityManager.merge(Color.RED);
```

But this solution works only with Hibernate. Is there a way to do similar with EclipseLink? After some research, I didn't found any functionality in EclipseLink to do that.